# HTML code keeps on displaying in my webpage

Tags: html, node.js

my 
 and  etc are being displayed on the webpage.
the input that is passed through a function that creates/breaks it into lines and stanzas, look like this:

```
    [
      'If you can talk with crowds and keep your virtue,',
      'Or walk with Kings—nor lose the common touch,',
      'If neither foes nor loving friends can hurt you,',
      'If all men count with you, but none too much;',
      'If you can fill the unforgiving minute',
      'With sixty seconds’ worth of distance run,',
      'Yours is the Earth and everything that’s in it,',
      'And—which is more—you’ll be a Man, my son!'
    ]
```

the function i am using to insert the necessary breaks an new lines look like this:

```
    function formatPoem(poem) {
        const stanzas = poem.map((stanza) => {
            console.log(stanza)
        const lines = stanza.map(line => `${line}`)
        return lines.join("\r");
    });
  
    return stanzas.join("<br>");
    }
```

I am using node.js and ejs.
Can someone assist me with this

I want the poem to reflect the structure of the poem without displaying the HTML code

Comment: What is the error you are facing? What is the expected output? What have you tried to solve your problem?? Add all of this into your Q. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you're HTML is escaped (`&lt;` and `&gt;`) then it's not happening in the function you shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Express, you need to use Class: http.Server.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```